# DATEPARSE in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to convert "Thu, 01 Nov 2018 00:00:00 Z" into a date using calculated field and getting errors.

I was trying to consult http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html?_fsi=KFxzRKAj&_fsi=KFxzRKAj but without any luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your original data, you can create this calculated field:

```
MID([Date],5,12)
```

You should be able to get just the portion of string you need to get date information.

Once you've created it, you just need to click on the icon of that string dimension and change it into date type.

You should be getting something like this:
[image]

Otherwise you can directly enter the parse code into your calculated field:

```
DATE(DATEPARSE ( " dd MMM yyyy", MID([Date],5,12) ))
```